# Determining if http://foo.com redirects to http://www.foo.com

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I have a list of ~150 URLs. I need to find out whether each domain resolves to `www.domain.com` or just `domain.com`.

Comment: Sort of confused by the question. Are you trying to understand how to use arrays or resolve DNS? Perhaps any sample code you have written might be worth posting.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. Basically, all I want to know is if I type domain.com, does it redirect to www.domain.com, or just domain.com, like StackOverflow does. Is that a little better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways that a domain name could 'resolve' or 'redirect' to another:

1. Making an HTTP request for `foo.com` could respond with an [HTTP redirect response code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) like 301, sending the browser to `www.foo.com`.

   ```
   phrogz$ curl -I http://adobe.com
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 22:19:33 GMT
   Server: Apache
   Location: http://www.adobe.com/
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   ```
2. The web page sent back by the server might include a [`<meta>` redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#For_redirection):

   ```html
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.adobe.com/">
   ```
3. The web page sent back by the server might include JavaScript redirection:

   ```js
   location.href = 'http://www.adobe.com';
   ```

*Which of these do you need to test for?*

### Reading HTTP Response Header

To detect #1 use the [`net/http` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) built into Ruby:

```
require "net/http"
req = Net::HTTP.new('adobe.com', 80)
response = req.request_head('/')
p response.code, response['Location']
#=> "301"
#=> "http://www.adobe.com/"
```

### Reading HTML Meta Headers

To detect #2, you'll need to actually fetch the page, parse it, and look at the contents. I'd use Nokogiri for this:

```
require 'open-uri' # …if you don't need #1 also, this is easier
html = open('http://adobe.com').read

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
if meta = doc.at_xpath('//meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]')
  # Might give you "abobe.com" or "www.adobe.com"
  domain = meta['content'][%r{url=([^/"]+(\.[^/"])+)},1]
end
```

### Reading JavaScript

…you're on your own, here. :) You could attempt to parse the JavaScript code yourself, but you'd need to actually run the JS to find out if it ever actually redirects to another page or not.

Comment: Thanks so much. I believe the HTTP response code should be fine.

Comment: Good but your net/http example only follows a single redirect. Often there are several.

Comment: @pguardiario A great point; as I did not hand off any prepackaged code exactly suited to the OP's needs, hopefully s/he will implement a loop that keeps fetching as long as it's being redirected. Or perhaps the OP only needs to know _if_ there's a redirect involved, and not necessarily the final destination.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this done very successfully with the [resolv std library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html).

```
require 'resolv'
["google.com", "ruby-lang.org"].map do |domain|
  [domain, Resolv.getaddress(domain)]
end
```

Comment: To Expand on that a little:
["google.com", "ruby-lang.org"].map do |domain|
  [domain, Resolv.getaddress(domain)]
end

Comment: Doesn't that just do a reverse DNS lookup and return the IP address?

Comment: Right, that will just get the IP addresses and shove them into an array, but that map can be the more complex to look up CNAMES, etc. The one thing this won't do that might be desired is HTTP redirects.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanize way:

```
require 'mechanize'
Mechanize.new.head('http://google.com').uri.host
#=> "www.google.com.ph"
```

Comment: Why does the url end with ph?

Comment: Because that's where google redirected to (I'm in Philippines).